# Добавить небольшой блок в круг

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Появилась проблема - нужно сделать блок такого вида:

[image: Пример блока из макета]

Не знаю, как верно сделать блок с единичкой.
Попробовал спозиционировать `float: left;` и поровнять `margin`'ами, но мне кажется, что это не самый лучший вариант, плюс не срабатывает `margin-left`.

Буду рад помощи.

```css
.top {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 110px;
  border: 6px solid #f7d701;
}

.circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #f7d701;
  border-radius: 110px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 67px;
  font-size: 19px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"> 
  <div class="circle">1</div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/brpZBM

Comment: Если ответ помог решить вашу проблему, вы можете отметить его принятым, нажав на галочку рядом с ним.

Comment: @Cheg, ответов много, и увы не могу решить какой лучший. Поэтому, призываю эксперта/модератора помочь с решением лучшего ответа.

Answer (score 4):

```css
div {
  width: 10em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  border: 6px solid red;
  text-align: right;
}

div:before { /* для вертикального центрирования */
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-top: 100%; /* высота равна ширине */
}

div:after {
  content: "1";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  background: blue;
  line-height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* ПЕРЕДУМАЛ: margin-right: -3px; /* половина от border-width родителя */
  transform: translateX(50%); /* и подвинуть ещё на половину мелкого круга */
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Твой ответ хотя бы чем то отличается от двух остальных :) +1

Comment: Потому что является нормальным)) зачем плодить лишнюю вложенность и лишние элементы

Answer (score 2):

Используйте для этого абсолютное позиционирования для блока с единицей. В отличие от вашего варианта с `float` и `margin`, вариант с `position:absolute` выводит "единицу" из общего потока, и таким образом она в дальнейшем не будет "мешать", сли вам потребуется, напривер, добавить в большой круг новые элементы.

```css
.top {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 110px;
  border: 6px solid #f7d701;
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #f7d701;
  border-radius: 110px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 19px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div class="circle">1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.top {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 110px;
  border: 6px solid #f7d701;
}

.circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #f7d701;
  border-radius: 110px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 67px;
  font-size: 19px;
  
  position: relative;
  right: -25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div class="circle">1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Совсем как на картинке:

```css
.top {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 110px;
  border: 6px solid #f7d701;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  background: black;
}

.circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #f7d701;
  border-radius: 110px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 19px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  font-size: 175%;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div class="circle"><b>1</b></div>
</div>
```